# How to send concurrent 10,000 post request using python?

Tags: python, testing, load-testing, performance-testing

I developed REST server. I hosted that one my virtual machine nginx server. Now i want to do bench marking by sending 10,000 concurrent request per second. So any solution for this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

10,000 per second?  You'll need lots of machines to do this.

Write a client that can POST requests serially and then replicate it on several machines.

Comment: Is there exist some tool like Apache bench marking tool which sends too many concurrent request ?

but i don't wanna to use it because i want to capture response of REST  client.

Comment: Check out JMeter.  It can run your test, but you'll still need several instances to ramp up to that load.

Answer (score 3):

[locust](http://locust.io/) will do the job . JMeter will eventually run out of steam for huge loads because of the use of threads used to generate load .

Locust uses [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) - no threads , less limitations.

With locust , the load can even be generated from a [cluster](http://docs.locust.io/en/latest/running-locust-distributed.html) if one machine's hardware is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [gevent](http://gevent.org).

Monkey-patch everything with `gevent.monkey.patch_all`, write function that uses urllib2.urlopen for query and spawn it as greenlet for 10000 times.

However i doubt that you can do 10000 requests per second with Python (but i think you should try).

If tool does not matter and you just need to do simple POST requests without any logic, try [Apache Benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) instead of Python.

Answer (score 0):

programmatically you can create threads and do a url fetch by every thread but not sure if you can create 10,000 requests.